# how to get the variable from _.map

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, underscore.js

in my code I trying to take the results from callback function from de underscore lib, and when i give a console.log, the console gives me a undefined variable.

here is my code

```
  var newMenu 
    = _.map(this.state.forms.view, function(lista){
            if(lista.NivelHierarquia == 1)
            {
              console.log("printou", lista);
                lista['navi'] = [{text: lista.DescricaoObjetoMenu}];

                    _.map(lista['navi'], function(texto){
                          //for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(lista.filho).length; i++){
                                 texto['navilist'] = _.filter(lista.filho, {

                                  CodigoObjetoOrigemMenu : lista.CodigoObjetoMenu

                                })
                               //}
                             _.map(texto['navilist'], function (menu){
                                 menu['navilist'] = [{text: menu.DescricaoObjetoMenu}]
                                 console.log("menu", menu);
                               })
                      });
                  }

          });

 console.log(newMenu);
```

I need to return the value "menu" to the new variable "newMenu"

Comment: what is the input? please post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `_.map` to return something you have to return something in the `callback`

```
var newMenu = _.map(this.state.forms.view, function(lista){
    return 'something'
});
console.log(newMenu); // ['something', 'something', 'something']
```